# How to receive data when clients are behind NAT e.g. router - Python

Tags: python, networking

How to receive data when clients are behind NAT e.g. router?
I have simple app that can send data and receive data, it works great on LAN.
I want it to be **decentralized**. **Without need to manually configure the router.**

Comment: Be more specific in your questioning. For clients it should be irrelevant that they are behind a NAT. A client can establish a connection to a server no problem. If the server is behind a NAT you need to do port forwarding as mentioned by @attalos. This is done within the router settings.

Comment: Correct. I somehow assumed the second possibility, because it wouldn't matter otherwise.

Comment: Since it should be decentralized, everybody acts as client and server, so my answer still applies.

Answer (score 0):

You should find some kind of setting in your router, that allows you to route incoming requests to specific ports, to chosen IPs in your local network.

The keyword you are looking for is **Port Forwarding**.

Since you now specified, that you do not want change anything in the router, the only possibility is, that the person behind the NAT establishes a connection with the person not behind a NAT. The other way is not possible without accessing the router. If both, are behind a NAT, it is impossible.

Comment: I've heard about ,,hole punching", couldn't that be the solution? If not, then what is it?